# Как правильно?

Tags: ударение

Допустимо ли в слове новорож**ден**ный ударение на третьем слоге т.е. ново**рож**денный? И еще от**гул** (часто говорят**от**гул), но **вы**гул (вы**гул** не говорят  никогда).

Answer (score 3):

Новор**о**жденный - неправильно, но, к сожалению, очень часто встречается. Настолько часто, что некоторые, не слишком авторитетные в вопросах орфоэпии словари принимают этот вариант за допустимо-разговорный. Я не могу с этим согласиться.

Нормативно - отг**у**л и в**ы**гул, тут никаких вариантов нет и быть не может, ни с каких **о**тгулами (в этом значении) я не сталкивался. **О**тгул - это отзвук, отголосок, но слово весьма редкое.

А смещение на приставку в "выгул" объясняется особым "статусом" приставки ВЫ - в первичных глагольных формах она почти всегда ударная (иное возможно во вторичных отглагольных образованиях:  "выраж**е**ние", "вып**а**ривание", "выкол**а**чивать" и проч).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно только *новорожд**Ё**нный* и *отг**У**л*. Приставка "вы-" почти всегда ударная, поэтому с ней не сравнивайте, а в остальных случаях ударение на корень (*заг**у**л, разг**у**л*)